# Eclipse Luna - is is possible to make "Find/replace" dialog transparent?

Tags: eclipse, search, eclipse-luna

I am using `Eclipse Luna` with `EPIC` plugin under `CentOS 6.3`.

Is is possible to make "Find/replace" dialog (shown when clicking `CTRL + F`) transparent, so I can see matches below it when clicking on "Find" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are you using GNOME, I do not believe you can do it for a specific dialog.  It is either the entire application or nothing.  :(

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/684/transparent-windows/

Strangely enough I have done something similar in Windows OS.  There is a desktop tool called Dexpot, which has "Desktop Rules" feature that can apply transparency rule to dialog with a specific title.